# Application interfering with OS processes

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have created a simple application that starts a service to register an SMS broadcast receiver. The application works fine but I keep getting alerts that different process are not responding. The associated buttons are to "Force Close" or "Wait". The particular process varies. For example, "com.android.inputmethod.latin". Other times it mught the "mms" process.

I get these alerts under the 2.1 or 2.1-update1 platform but I do not however under the 2.2 platform.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the emulator? If yes, then those errors are safe to ignore. You can click any button you want.

Explanation: the emulator is notoriously slow. Because of this, the system says "hey, I've been trying to start this damn mms process for 20 seconds now, something must be wrong!" (because on an actual device it would never take 20 seconds to start it).